# Javascript Image Preview for page with lots of forms

Tags: javascript, image-upload

I have a bunch of forms on a page that allow a user to edit information for each respective form. One of the inputs for the form is an image upload.

The forms are of the form below:

```
<form class="myForm" ...>
    <div class="imagePreview"></div>
    <input type="file" name="myImage" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)" />
</form>
```

And I have javascript to handle the image preview as follows:

```
function handleFiles(files) {
    $(".obj").remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        var imageType = /image.*/;

        if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
            continue;
        }

        var pic_div = document.getElementById("imagePreview");
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.classList.add("obj");
        img.file = file;
        pic_div.appendChild(img);

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (
            function(aImg) { 
                return function(e) { 
                    aImg.src = e.target.result; 
                }; 
            }
        )(img);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

I want to replace the line:

```
var pic_div = document.getElementById("imagePreview");
```

with the appropriate line. This is where I am getting confused. I don't know how to refer to the div of class "imagePreview" for THIS FORM of class myForm.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're getting the div with the Id `imagePreview`, when the div in the form have the `imagePreview` CSS class, what you can do is either give the div the required id, more less like this:

```
<div id="imagePreview"></div>
```

Or, if you will have multiple divs with the same class get them using jQuery like this:

```
$(".imagePreview").each(function(index){
    //Do Something
});
```

Or:

```
var pic_div = $(".imagePreview")[0]
```

Comment: But I need to know whether the div with the class name "imagePreview" corresponds to the input that caused the onchange event to be called. How can I know which "imagePreview" corresponds to the input? I only want to change the imagePreview for the form that had an image file selected.

Comment: If you're going to have multiple forms (or inputs of the same kind), you can add an id number to the `handleFiles` function, `handleFiles(files, id)`, then use the id in `$(".imagePreview")[id]`, of course this id must be generated when you generate the forms/inputs

Comment: Ok thanks Rafael. It worked although I wish there was a more elegant solution. It seems like I should be able to traverse the DOM in some way so I don't have to provide the current index for each call to the function

Comment: You can traverse the DOM (read JQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/), but i recommend you not to, first, because it's not foolproof, and second, because it may be slower than simply addressing the element directly.